# How to get an EntityCollection<class> instead of just a class?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to convert a one-to-many relationship in entity framework to a many-to-many.

I've done the admin work and generated a database, which seems to be fine but now I'm running through the resulting errors and trying to get the code to compile. Most of it is fine, but one particular change is giving me a headache - I can't figure out the correct syntax. I'm sure I'm being very stupid here.

The original line was:

```
 addedService.CompiledDatabase = context.Databases.OfType<CompiledDatabase>().First();
```

But addedService.CompiledDatabase is no longer looking for a single instance of CompiledDatabase, it's looking for a collection: an EntityCollection to be precise.

I can't figure out how to get a linq/lambda query that will return a collection of the required type. Assistance gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like?

```
addedService.CompiledDatabase.Attach(context.Databases.OfType<CompiledDatabase>());
```

...if `addedService` is already in `context`.